# only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. why arr[i].shape is not working?

Tags: python, image, numpy, csv, tensorflow

I want to store image data into a CSV file to make some neural network model on it.
in mylist there are all images
convert_img_to_array function convert images into numpy array
in data_image array i store all images data
but when i print data_image[i].shape than it's show me an error
what's an error here.
here is my code

```
import io
import os
import csv
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
# from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
# from keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img

all_img = []
filename = 'images'
myList = []
myList = os.listdir(filename)
print(myList)
for img in myList:
    with open(f'{filename}/{img}', 'rb') as f:
        cur = f.read()
        all_img.append(cur)

data_image = []


def convert_img_to_array(img1):
    img1 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img1)).convert('L')
    data = np.asarray(img1)
    data = data / 255
    data = data[np.newaxis, ..., np.newaxis]
    data = tf.image.resize(data, [255, 255])
    print(data.shape)
    return data


for i in all_img:
    data_image.append(convert_img_to_array(i))
for i in data_image:
    print(data_image[i].shape)

with open('innovators.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(data_image[0])
    writer.writerow(data_image[1])
```

it shows me error on "print(data_image[i].shape)"

error

```
File "F:\create numpy data from images\create_array.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(data_image[i].shape)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1004, in __index__
    return self._numpy().__index__()
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

is there any other way to store all images into a NumPy array with the same dimension than? Please tell me
Thank you for try to solve it.

Comment: What are you trying to do in that line?  What is `i`?  An index or an element of the tensor?  That mix of iteration and indexing doesn't make sense - not even with simple python lists!

Comment: The error basically tells you that i in your case isnt an int value which you can use for indexing. This makes sense as you are adding two lines before that a nd.array to your data_image array. If you want to have the index value of a particular element use  _idx, element in enumerate(data_image):_

Comment: thank you for commenting i understand my problem. so is there any other to store data in csv files ?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have a directory c:\images that holds your images

```
img_dir=r'c:\images'
all_img = []
file_list-os.listdir(img_dir)
for f in file_list:
    fpath=os.path.join(img_dir, f)
    img=cv2.imread(fpath)
    img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # convert to rgb image
    img=img/255 # scale pixels between 0 and 1
    all_img.append(img) # now you have a list containing your images
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.. but question is not this. I know how to make a list of images but question is that how to store that images data into array